# Unable to resolve class JunitAdapter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pom.xml, spock

I wrote a test where I am importing a class from package `com/intel/epgsw/JunitAdapter.groovy`

When I try to run the test, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.5:testCompile (groovy) on project jenkinsfile-test-shared-library: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath. InvocationTargetException: startup failed:
[ERROR] src/test/groovy/CloneTestSpec.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class src.com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter
[ERROR] @ line 3, column 1.
[ERROR] import com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter
[ERROR] ^
```

Test file is present in: `src/test/groovy`

Class that needs to be imported: `com/intel/epgsw/JunitAdapter.groovy`
My test file is CloneTestSpec.groovy

Here is the tree :

```
src
│   ├── com
│   │   └── intel
│   │       ├── epgsw
│   │       │   ├── TestResultEnum.groovy
│   │       │   ├── **JunitAdapter.groovy**
│   │       │   
│   └── test
│       ├── com
│       │   └── intel
│       │       └── epgsw
│       ├── epgsw
│       │   └── FooBar98.groovy
│       ├── groovy
│       │   ├── **CloneTestSpec.groovy**
```

This is a section of my pom.xml

```
<plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                                        <executions>
                                                <execution>
                                                        
                                                        <configuration>
                                                                
                                                        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                                                                <includes>
                                                                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                                                                        <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
                                                                        <include>**/*Spec</include>
                                                                </includes>
                                                                
                                                        </configuration>
                                                </execution>
                                        </executions>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>${groovy.gmaven.pluginVersion}</version>
                                        <executions>
                                                <execution>
                                                        <id>groovy</id>
                                                        <goals>
                                                                <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                                                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                                        </goals>
                                                </execution>
                                        </executions>
                                                        <configuration>
                                                                <sources>
                                                                        <source>
                                                                         <directory>src</directory>
                                                                                <includes>
                                                                                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>

                                                                                </includes>
                                                                        </source>
                                                                </sources>
                                                                <testSources>
                                                                        <testSource>
                                                                                <directory>src/test/groovy/com/intel/epgsw</directory>
                                                                                <includes>
                                                                                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                                                                </includes>
                                                                        </testSource>
                                                                </testSources>
                                                        </configuration>
                                </plugin>
                        </plugins>
```

Comment: I commented on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70062088/1082681) already, trying to educate you about why an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary to precisely answer your question. So please, read the article I linked to and edit your question, providing a full, minimal example project reproducing the problem, either inline or on GitHub (preferred). Please also give your questions more love, formatting them properly (I just did that for you). Thank you. I know you are new here, no problem. But please try and improve.

Comment: Are you sure that the package name is `src.com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter` and not simply `com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter`?

Comment: Yes the package is com.intel.epgsw
I meant the directory while specifying the problem.

Comment: But the directory should be `src/test/groovy`, like you also said. So there is an inconsistency here. `unable to resolve class src.com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter` means that either an import statement or your directory structure are wrong, containing a superfluous `src`. That is why I need to see the MCVE, if you cannot figure it out by yourself.

Comment: I tried importing with com.intel.epgsw.JunitAdapter. Still getting the same problem. Just to make sure everything is working, I tried copying the class JunitAdapter to my test CloneTestSpec.groovy, and then it was working fine. 
I have updated my question, added the tree structure of my project. What else should I add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory layout is chaotic. Please move all your test classes into the `src/test/groovy` base folder. There, you create a directory structure according to your package structure. For example (I cannot say for sure without seeing the package declarations in each file), assuming that

- all application classes are Java classes,
- all test classes are Groovy classes and
- all classes are in the exact same package `com.intel.epgsw`:

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        intel
          epgsw
            ApplicationClassA.java
            ApplicationClassB.java
  test
    groovy
      com
        intel
          epgsw
            TestResultEnum.groovy
            JunitAdapter.groovy
            FooBar98.groovy
            CloneTestSpec.groovy
```

If any of my above assumptions are false, you need to adjust the directory structure accordingly. But your chaotic directory layout with 3 different base directories causes the trouble you are facing. Please do learn some Java, Groovy and Maven basics, especially the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: You assumed it correctly. the package was com.intel.epgsw
creating a directory like you suggested solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot.