# unable to resolve class com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification

Tags: groovy, pom.xml, spock, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-spock

I am trying to run some spock tests with **Maven**. I already ran tests before with ***groovy version*** 2.4. Now when I switched to 2.5+, it shows some error.

My minimal **pom** is:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.14</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0-groovy-2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jenkins-spock</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <forkCount>1</forkCount>
              <includes>
                <include>${test.pattern}</include>
              </includes>
              <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <root.loglevel>${test.loglevel}</root.loglevel>
                <root.appender>Stdout</root.appender>
                <test.loglevel>${test.loglevel}</test.loglevel>
                <logdir>${logdir}</logdir>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>addTestSources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>
                  <directory>src</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                  </includes>
                </source>
              </sources>
              <testSources>
                <testSource>
                  <directory>test</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                  </includes>
                </testSource>
              </testSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
src
│   └── test
│       ├── vars
│       │   ├── gitCloneSpec.groovy
│       │   ├── GitRepoCloneSpec.groovy
vars
|   └── ├── gitClone.groovy
│       ├── GitRepoClone.groovy
```

Here is the error report: Although I already have dependency **jenkins-spock** in my pom, why do I get this error?

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6.1:compile (default) on project devops-pdk-psl: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: startup failed:
[ERROR] src/test/vars/gitCloneSpec.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification
[ERROR]  @ line 1, column 1.
[ERROR]    import com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification;
[ERROR]    ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] src/test/vars/GitRepoCloneSpec.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification
[ERROR]  @ line 1, column 1.
[ERROR]    import com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification;
[ERROR]    ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 2 errors
```

Comment: I reformatted and syntax-highlighted your code snippets. Please note that your POM snippet is **not** a minimal POM, but less than that, just an incomplete snippet. Furthermore, your directory structure looks weird. I think that like this, it is difficult to help you. Please publish a minimal reproducer project ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) on GitHub in order for everyone to be able to reproduce your problem. I tried to explain to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70062088/1082681) that incomplete information usually yields bad or no answers, Does that help you?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, as I cannot see your imports, packages names etc. 
Please provide some basic code files (including imports in your vars and package names in your src files)

Comment: Oh, one more thing: According to your POM, you are trying to use `spock-core:2.0-groovy-2.5` with `groovy-all:2.4.14`, i.e. a Spock version designed for Groovy 2.5 with Groovy 2.4. Hmm...